# HTML - checkbox conditionally checked

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have written this simple jsp page: I want to show a simple list of object (Person), with a label (showing the name of the person) and a checkbox (that shows if the person is at least 18 yo).

I also write the corresponding Java class 'Person', with a String (name) and a boolean (isAdult).

Here is my jsp (personList is a List of Person objects)

```
 <table>
     <th>NAME</th>
     <th>IS ADULT</th>
        <c:forEach var="person" items="${personList}">
           <tr>
             <td>${person.name}</td>
             <td>
               <input type="checkbox" value="checked"/>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

This portion of code shows me a list in which all checkboxes are not checked (names are correct.

How could I obtain that every checkbox in the list is checked (or not), referring to the boolean attribute 'isAdult' of the Person object?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `EL` ternary operator like this:

```
 <input type="checkbox"  ${person.adult ? 'checked' : ''}>
```

`${person.adult}` will invoke `isAdult` method that encapsulating `adult` attribute.